# Excel linked pictures change scale after copying sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have created a dashboard sheet by using the camera tool to paste graphs from other sheets as linked picture in the dashboard sheet. When I copy the whole sheet (by right clicking the sheet tab) and paste it as a new sheet in the same workbook, the scale of my graphs reverts to the scale of the original graph. This results in the whole dashboard being distorted with overlapping graphs.

What did I do already:

- googled it
- I have tried numerous combinations of "Lock aspect ratio" and "Relative to original picture size" under Size, and "Move but don't size with cells", "Don't move or size with cells" under Properties.
- It looks like copying every object one by one works, but if you copy the whole sheet it distorts everything.

Another guy posted exactly the same problem [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/paste-as-picture-link-results-in-distorted-picture/b4df581e-2cff-403b-9737-c9327846d048) but he didn't get any answer.

It would be great if someone is able to help me with this annoying problem.

Johan

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem and the one in your link but I couldn't do it. Can you specify the steps to do what you stated in your first sentence?

Comment: @Andrew, Here's a post I did about this: http://yoursumbuddy.com/camera-tool-now-with-33-more-picture/

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @DougGlancy did you receive any answers to  your problem?

Comment: Not really, beyond the hardcoded fix I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around

- Create a chart object (delete all chart related graphics = empty area).
- Set width, height of chart object equal to your linked picture.
- Click your linked picture to select and copy (Ctrl+C) then unselect.
- Click chart object to select and paste (Ctrl+P)
- DONE!

Now, your linked picture size won't change anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - when copying a worksheet with a paste link picture and it loses scale

I got around it by creating a text box in the origin square and then putting the picture into the text box

Then when copying the sheet with the linked picture file it does not lose scale